# hide with js an HTML table row <tr> so that it takes up no space

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating rows in a table with javascript. When I try to hide those rows, it hides the row, but the space of the row is still taken.
My code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                isHide = false;
               if(i<3)
                    isHide = true;
                var table = document.getElementById("table");
                var tr = document.createElement("TR");
                if (isHide == true) {
                    tr.style.visibility = "none";
                }
                else {
                    tr.style.visibility = "visible";
                }
                table.appendChild(tr);
                var td1 = document.createElement("TD");
                var td2 = document.createElement("TD");                    
                tr.appendChild(td1);
                tr.appendChild(td2);
                var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
                checkbox.type = "checkbox";
                checkbox.name = i;
                checkbox.value = i;
                checkbox.id = i;
                var label = document.createElement('label')
                label.htmlFor = i;
                label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i.toString()));
                if (isHide == false){
                    var mybr = document.createElement('br');
                }

                td1.appendChild(label);
                td2.appendChild(checkbox);

            }
```

How do I hide rows in a way that they do not take up any space?

Comment: to hide: `tr.style.display = 'none';` to unhide: `tr.style.display = '';`

Comment: that what i'm doing : tr.style.visibility = "none"; but it takes up space

Comment: can you see the difference between what I said and what you are doing? `display` !== `visibility`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `tr.style.visibility = "none";` to `tr.style.display = 'none'`

With `display:none`, there will be no space allocated for the `tr` as `tr`  will not appear on the page and we can interact with the `tr` through the DOM.

With `visibility:hidden` the `tr` is not visible but it takes up the space allocated to it. This means that `tr` is rendered on the page but does not seem to be visible.

Comment: you're sort of almost right ... except that you need to change the (incorrect value that wouldn't hide a thing anyway) `tr.style.visibility = "none"; ` to `tr.style.display = 'none';`

Comment: Do you know how can I show all the hidden rows without Jquery?

Comment: You mean by using CSS?